# How to work around conflicts with Ruby versions and pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg

I'm working on someone's website, trying to get Rails to run. The files sent to me included the gemfile, which had `gem 'pg', '0.21.0'. However, when I run`bundler install` I get

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby ":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby  (~> 2.6.6.0)

    pg (= 0.21.0) was resolved to 0.21.0, which depends on
      ruby  (>= 2.0.0)

    pg (= 0.21.0) was resolved to 0.21.0, which depends on
      ruby  (< 2.5, >= 2.0) x64-mingw32
```

Additionally, if I try to run `rails server` or `rails -v` after such a failed attempt, I get

```
Could not find gem 'pg (= 0.21.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm running Ruby 2.6.6p146 and Rails 4.2.10, although I could change the Rails version easily, and it doesn't seem to affect this. 
I'm on Windows 10 if it helps.

It appears I need to use a more recent version of pg. When I try that (the earliest compatible version being 1.1.4) `bundle install` works well. But then, `rails server` throws

```
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

It appears I'm stuck between these two errors, where, based on my version of pg in the gemfile, I'm bound to get one of them, and neither allows me to run `rails server`.

Is there a way to get around this, preferably, a solution that will allow me to keep 0.21.0 in the gemfile? I'm also happy for a solution that gets around the second error instead.

Here's the full stack trace for the second error:

```
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x64-mingw32/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Struct::Passwd
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:116: warning: already initialized constant Forwardable::VERSION
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/forwardable-1.3.1/lib/forwardable/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:117: warning: already initialized constant Forwardable::FORWARDABLE_VERSION
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/forwardable-1.3.1/lib/forwardable/version.rb:4: warning: previous definition of FORWARDABLE_VERSION was here
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.10 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        56: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        55: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        54: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        53: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        52: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        51: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        50: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        49: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        48: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        47: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
        46: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        45: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
        44: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        43: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        42: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        41: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        40: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config.ru:in `<main>'
        39: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config.ru:in `new'
        38: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        37: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        36: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        35: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        34: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        33: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        32: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        31: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        30: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
        29: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
        28: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        27: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        26: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        25: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        24: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        23: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        22: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        21: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': can't activate pg (~> 0.15), already activated pg-1.1.4-x64-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
        51: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        50: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        49: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        48: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        47: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        46: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        45: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        44: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        43: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        42: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
        41: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        40: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
        39: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        38: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        37: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        36: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        35: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config.ru:in `<main>'
        34: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config.ru:in `new'
        33: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        32: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        31: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        30: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        29: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        28: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        27: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        26: from C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Jobs/You3dit/y3dialpha/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        25: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
        24: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
        23: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        22: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        21: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: This is never a good situation; It results from the code, gems and Ruby not being maintained to keep everything working together. Ruby, Rails and gems that are maintained will slowly leave behind old code. Keep three servers, or at least three instances of the code. Your development branch should run on the bleeding edge of Ruby, Rails and gems, so you have advance notice of problems. Your test machine is your next version being pushed to production and runs the candidate Ruby, Rails, gems and your Rails code. Production lags a couple versions and runs what you know is stable.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I have a similar one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the version level of `pg` at least for now, your main solution is to drop back to an earlier version of ruby. You mention you are running 2.6.6, but per the error:

```
pg (= 0.21.0) was resolved to 0.21.0, which depends on
      ruby  (< 2.5, >= 2.0) x64-mingw32
```

So, that version of `pg` only works with ruby up to (but not including 2.5). Install an older version of ruby, ensure that things are running correctly, and then you can look to begin upgrading both the rails and ruby versions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is that when I get downgrade Ruby, I get a similar error but with other gems, saying that they require a higher upgraded version.